# PHP: How to get base URL of a web page using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get contents of someone's web page remotely. The URL is something like:

`http://www.somewebsite.com/post/slug-of-the-post/`

And I want to get and display/output via PHP `cURL` is the base URL which is `http://www.somewebsite.com/`

What code to use should look like?

Comment: It would be nice if you put some effort into your question, e.g. what have you tried and how's that not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
echo $url_parts['scheme'].'://.'.$url_parts['host'];
```

This returns the URL in the current cURL session, parses the url, then displays the scheme and the host.